# Installing Firebase in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, npm

I tried to install Firebase in React-Native project using **npx install --save @react-native-firebase/app**.It gives the following error.How can I fix this error?
I'm using my android phone as the emulator.

```
npx: installed 1 in 3.087s
command not found: install
```

Comment: try to update your nodejs and npm to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to type 'npm' instead of 'npx'.  npx is for running programs installed by npm.